# Creating pairs from an Array?

Tags: ruby, arrays

Is there a simple way to create pairs from an array?

For example, if I have an array `[1,2,3,4]` how would I go about trying to return this array?

```
[[1,2], [1,3], [1,4], [2,1], [2,3], [2,4], [3,1], [3,2], [3,4], [4,1], [4,2], [4,3]]
```

Every element is paired with every other other element except itself, and duplicates are allowed.

Comment: What you describe is not an array, not even a valid Ruby code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Array#permutation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Array.html#method-i-permutation) for this:

```
[1,2,3,4].permutation(2).to_a
# => [[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 1], [2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 4], [4, 1], [4, 2], [4, 3]]
```

Comment: How can I access one of the elements in each of the pair, for example say I want to increment the second value in each pair by 1. e.g. [1,3],[1,4].....

Answer (score 2):

```
[1,2,3,4].permutation(2).map{ |n| "(#{ n.join(",") })" }
# => ["(1,2)", "(1,3)", "(1,4)", "(2,1)", "(2,3)", "(2,4)", "(3,1)", "(3,2)", "(3,4)", "(4,1)", "(4,2)", "(4,3)"]
```